# Two segmented controls using one action

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two separate segmented controls, both with the same segments. How can I set the second segmented control based on the first segmented control?

If the gallons segment is selected in the top segmented control, I want the bottom segmented control to automatically switch to gallons.
[Screenshot of the segmented controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h8Hu.png)

Comment: Set `selectedSegmentIndex` of the second segmented control inside the action of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
segmentedControl1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeAction), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
func changeAction() {
    segmentedControl2.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentedControl1.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```

Comment: This worked and was exactly what I needed. Thank you